# C++ lambda ambiguous call

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying to have two eachPixel functions. One returns an image, and the other returns nothing. I'm getting "call to eachPixel is ambiguous"  even though I am specifying the return type of the lambda.

How can I resolve the ambiguity?

```
// this one does not return an image
void eachPixel(const QImage &image, const std::function <void (uint)>& pixelFunc, const QRect &bounds=QRect()) {
...

    for (int y=region.y(); y<=region.bottom(); y++) {
        for (int x=region.x(); x<=region.right(); x++) {
            pixelFunc(image.pixel(x,y));
        }
    }
}

// This one returns an image
QImage eachPixel(const QImage &image, const std::function <uint (uint)>& pixelFunc, const QRect &bounds=QRect()) {
...

    QImage out(image.size(), image.format());
    for (int y=region.y(); y<=region.bottom(); y++) {
        for (int x=region.x(); x<=region.right(); x++) {
            out.setPixel(x,y, pixelFunc(image.pixel(x,y)));
        }
    }
    return out;
}

void test_pixelFunc() {
    QImage image(300,200, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    image.fill(Qt::blue);

    QImage out = eachPixel(image, [] (uint p) -> uint { //uint specified!!
        return qRgb(qRed(p), qBlue(p), qGreen(p)); // swap green and blue channels
    }, QRect (0,0, 300, 200));
    out.save("test_pixelfunc.png");


    int accumulator=0;
    eachPixel(image, [&accumulator](uint p) -> void { // void specified!
        accumulator++;
    }, QRect (0,0, 300, 200));
    qDebug() << "accumulator" << accumulator;

};
```

Comment: I think problem is lambda which returns `uint` can be bound to `std::function<void(uint)>` as it is fine to ignore returned value

Comment: Tag dispatching is the standard way of discriminating functions like these.

Comment: Are you going to use these functions in generic code (where each one can be used based on type)? If not then giving them different names is a simplest solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use templates and SFINAE on the return type of the function you pass in.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<void, decltype(std::declval<T>()(1))>, int> = 0>
void foo (T f) {
    // std::function<void(int)> func = f;
    // if you really need a std::function
    f(1);
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int, decltype(std::declval<T>()(1))>, int> = 0>
int foo (T f) {
    return f(1);
}

int main() {
    foo([](int x) { std::cout << "void " << x << '\n'; });

    foo([](int x) { std::cout << "int\n"; return x; });
}
```

For c++11 you can use `std::is_same` and `std::enable_if` directly.

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<void, decltype(std::declval<T>()(1))>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo (T f) {
    f(1);
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, decltype(std::declval<T>()(1))>::value, int>::type = 0>
int foo (T f) {
    return f(1);
}
```

Comment: So this is inline with what I want, but clang is telling me error: no template named enable_if_t' in namespace std'. I'm rather new to SFINAE. I've included <type_traits> as well.

Comment: It requires c++17. It's only a convenience alias though so it's easily re-written to c++11/14. I can post a c++11 version when I'm back at a computer.

Comment: Got it compiling with the c++17 flag.  Thanks! If you update the example to something compatible with 11 or 14 that'd be great! It's the only thing causing me to use that flag.

Comment: So this is great! But now I want to add two params to the lambda: foo(1,2,3) and am getting  candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = (lambda no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at ....

Comment: @UserOneFourTwo Then you can add the params in the `enable_if` part. `decltype(std::declval<T>()(1))` => `decltype(std::declval<T>()(1, 2, 3))`.

Comment: This is awesome... but doesn't work for me because of how it interacts with other template things I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can add ignored parameter to one of lambdas to help resolve ambiguity:

```
struct noreturn_tag {};
void foo( std::function<void(int,noreturn_tag)>);
void foo( std::function<int(int)>);

int main() {
    foo( []( int ) { return 0; } );
    foo( []( int, noreturn_tag ) {} );
}
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/vyHgh7)