# Why is this lambda ambiguous?

Tags: c++, lambda

The answers at [C++ lambda ambiguous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629394/c-lambda-ambiguous-call) suggest some workarounds, but they do not explain why a lambda expression is ambiguous when passed to a function overloaded on `std::function` with different return types:

```
#include <functional>

enum class Prognosis
{
    OK,
    Danger,
    Error,
    Fatal
};

bool attempt(std::function<void()> fn) noexcept
{
   try {
        fn();
        return true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool attempt(std::function<bool()> fn) noexcept
{
    try {
        return fn();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Prognosis attempt(std::function<Prognosis()> fn) noexcept
{
    try {
        return fn();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return Prognosis::Fatal;
    }
}

int main()
{
    if (attempt([]()->bool { return true; })) // <-- ambiguous call
       return static_cast<int>(attempt([]()->Prognosis { return Prognosis::Danger; })); // <-- also ambiguous
    return static_cast<int>(Prognosis::Error);
}
```

If I remove the overload on `std::function<void()>` there is no longer any ambiguity.

The lambda specifies a return type, so why can't the compiler choose the correct overload?

Verified [at godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zkuh5r) in C++11 and C++17.

Comment: The `attempt` overloads on parameters `std::function<something>`.  A lambda is not a `std::function`, it gets converted.  Which one it converts to is ambiguous.

Comment: @TonyTannous All of the `attempt` overloads take exactly one argument.

Comment: `std::function<bool()> lambda = []() { return true; };` will work. As lambdas are not std::function but can be assigned to.

Comment: Because you can construct `std::function<void()>` from a closure that returns a `bool`, or any other value for that matter: `std::function<void()> fn = []() -> bool { return true; };` is perfectly cromulent C++, and your closure can be used for implicit conversion of the parameter to two different functions. The End.

Comment: @SamVarschavchik You should write an answer, then.

Comment: @NathanOliver  That proposed dupe is closer, but it doesn't explain why the calls aren't ambiguous when the overload on `std::function<void()>` is taken away.

Comment: @Spencer Like the dupe says, there is no way for the compiler to pick between `attempt(std::function<void()> fn)` and `attempt(std::function<bool()> fn)` when given `bool()` as both are valid.  Once you remove the void, there isn't a problem.  The same thing happens with `attempt(std::function<void()> fn)` and `attempt(std::function<Prognosis()> fn)` when using `Prognosis()`

Comment: @NathanOliver But not between `attempt(std::function<bool()>)` and `attempt(std::function<Prognosis()>)` . Apparently `std::function<void()>` is special for some reason.

Comment: @Spencer That's beacuse `std::function<void()>` just discards the return type.  With `std::function<bool()>` and `std::function<Prognosis()>` you can't do that since it will actually need to return something.

Comment: @NathanOliver and everything in the dupe is about variations on  `std::function<void(` _something_ `)>`.